# How to multiply quantity and record C#

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone-8.1, multiplication

I am new to c# and app developement. I am trying to get Value which is in a listview to be multiplied by quantity entered in a textbox by user. My code is below:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Menu.PassedData data = e.Parameter as Menu.PassedData;

        if (data != null) //If data is not 0 
        {
            PassedData.Add(data); //Increment data in list view

            double tempTotalValue = 0;
            foreach (var record in PassedData)
            {
                tempTotalValue = tempTotalValue + record.Value;
                Totaltxt.Text = String.Format(new CultureInfo("en-GB"),"{0:C}", tempTotalValue);

                textBox3.Text = string.Format("{0:Q2}", record.Value * double.Parse(quanttextBox.Text));    //The code to multiply user input of quantity by each Value produced
            }

            TotalValue = tempTotalValue;
        }
    }
```

**Textbox in Listview which displays the the value of each item**

```
  <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Value}" IsReadOnly="True" FontSize="15" />
```

**Textbox which displays Total Value**

```
<TextBox x:Name="Totaltxt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="45" Margin="250,461,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" TextChanged="Totaltxt_TextChanged" Text="{Binding TotalValue}" />
```

**Error when running**

```
An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
```

**Troublshooting tips**

```
When converting a string to datetime, parse the string before putting each variable in the date and time object
```

What I am trying to do is multiply the value of each item produced in the listview by user input and for the totalValue to be updated accordingly so basically quantity * Each Value in list view. Hope this question made sense.

Comment: what does the error message say..? double should be initialized to `0.0`
for example `var mytype = 2.0m; m=Decimal` `var mytype = 2.0d; d=Double` `var mytype = 2.0f; f=Float` can you tell us what happens when you are debugging the code..?

Comment: Can you use `double.Parse(quanttextBox.Text)` separately and debug? and also can you show what is the value of  `quanttextBox.Text`?

Comment: The question has been updated with error message and trouble shooting tips.

Comment: What is the value of `quanttextBox.Text`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be safer doing the conversion of the user input into a local variable before trying to use it in a calculation:

```
double result;
if (double.TryParse(quanttextBox.Text, out result))
{
    textBox3.Text = (record.Value * result).ToString();
}
```

Then if the user doesn't enter a valid numeric value your code won't fail.

However, the cause of your bug appears to be that you are trying to format your result as though it were a DateTime rather than a double.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. The multiplication did work! however it only works for the first record in the listview. Should I create a seperate listview for quantity? as I want the  text box to increment everytime an item is selected as then each item in the list view can be multiplied?

Comment: @SmithSunny - you'll need to add the result to your running total

Comment: What do you mean? wheres the running total?